# Recursion and stackoverflow

Tags: c#, recursion

I have class like

```
 public class Question
    {
        private readonly int questionID;
                private List<Question> similarquestions; // Similarity is bidirectional
}
```

to get all the nested classes I use recursion using method like

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Traversal<T>(
    T root,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChildren)
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    yield return root;

    var children = getChildren(root);
    if (children == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        foreach (var node in Traversal(child, getChildren))
        {
            yield return node;
        }
    }
}
```

I use it like

```
var  classes = Traversal(movie, x => x.similarquestions)
```

but it give stackoverflow Exception any idea how to fix that please

Comment: Run it in the debugger and see if the recursion is actually working.

Comment: If `Question`s point to each other then this will never terminate.

Comment: aha got it , so how can solve such a problem ?

Comment: Keep a list of questions already traversed and do not process them again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since similarity is bi-directional, you need to keep a "visited" list and check against it:

```
List<Question> visited = new List<Question>();

public static IEnumerable<T> Traversal<T>(
    T root,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChildren)
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    //We visited this node!
    visited.Add(root);

    yield return root;

    var children = getChildren(root);
    if (children == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    //Don't re-visit nodes we have seen before!
    foreach (var child in children.Except(visited))
    {
        foreach (var node in Traversal(child, getChildren))
        {
            yield return node;
        }
    }
}
```

There are other ways to check against the visited list as well, but this will give you an idea of how to do it. Also, if this is being called multiple times, be sure to clear/instantiate the list before starting a new traversal!